# backing up coverity PostgreSQL database to file

Tags: postgresql, coverity-prevent

We have the "coverity" tool setup and are trying to find a way to backup the database to a file, it uses I believe PostgreSQL.
How can we do this, is it using its own independent installation of PostgreSQL?

Comment: It didn't come with a manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it does use PostgreSQL, then there should be a pg_dump utility somewhere in the PostgreSQL installation.

Taking backups using pg_dump is very well explained in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: the above commands should not be used on Coverity's PostgreSQL instance.  Please only use the provided 'cov-admin-db backup' command.

Answer (score 5):

Even better answer..

```
cov-admin-db backup c:/mybackupfile
```

Answer (score 3):

When you installed Coverity Integrity Manager, it asked you if you want it to install and manage a PostgreSQL instance or if you want to connect to your own existing PostgreSQL instance that you then have to manage.

If you chose the former, then you would use the provided *cov-admin-db* command.

If you chose the latter then presumably you already do regular back-ups of your databases with *pg_dump*, you should do the same for the Coverity database.

Without knowing which of the two you chose, it's not clear which of the two answers already given is correct.

You can check which option you chose by looking in the file */config/system.properties* - if the first line is "*embedded_db=true*" then use the *cov-admin-db* command which is documented in the manual as well as in its own *--help* option.